# How to know if a customized random string function returns a string that matches a particular regex on Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, regex, random, regex-lookarounds, binance

### Context:

One of the great features that the `Binance API` has is to allow its users to set a custom order id (*a.k.a.* `newClientOrderId`) for every trade they place on the `Binance Futures` market, this feature becomes useful if someone wants to keep a track of the trades that were placed following a particular trading strategy.

According to its [`Offical Docs`](https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/futures/en/#new-order-trade), the parameter to be sent in the POST request to place the new order must be `newClientOrderId` and its value has to match this regex criteria: `^[\.A-Z\:/a-z0-9_-]{1,36}$`

### Problem:

I wrote a simple random string function on `Python3` that returns a random string based on 2 parameters which are a string and the length of the desired string to combine, here it is:

```
import random, string
def randstr(s, length):

    all_chars = string.ascii_lowercase
    result = s
    for i in range(length):
        result += random.choice(all_chars)
    return(result)
```

##### Tests

```
randstr('test1',5)
Out[14]: 'test1uljgp'

randstr('test1',2)
Out[15]: 'test1mo'

randstr('test1',5)
Out[16]: 'test1pbgjw'
```

How can I know if the output of my custom `randstr` function matches this regex criteria: `^[\.A-Z\:/a-z0-9_-]{1,36}$`? By knowing this, I will ensure that future developments related to this API will keep working nonstop.

Comment: As long as `s` meets the requirement, and `len(s)+length <= 36` then your result will meet the requirement (since every character in `string.ascii_lowercase` does).

Comment: `result = s + ''.join(random.choices(all_chars, k=length))`

Comment: May you explain why you suggest to use `result = s + ''.join(random.choices(all_chars, k=length))` instead of `result += random.choice(all_chars)`? It seems that `k` is a restriction for the maximum length to have in the string to add, but I tried with `randstr('test1',2)` and got `'test1hbtest1lw'` which have more than 2 characters after the initial string, so I don't get it  .

Comment: `random.choices(all_chars, k=length)` produces a list of `length` random characters from `all_chars`. `''.join` then turns that into a string. It has exactly the same effect as your loop, it's just a more concise way of writing it.

Comment: The idea is that you *replace* `result = s` and `for i in range(length):
        result += random.choice(all_chars)` with that single line

Comment: Oh, I see, so by just setting `all_chars = string.ascii_lowercase` `result = ""` `result += s + ''.join(random.choices(all_chars, k=length))` `return(result)` I get the same result as before, now I do get a random string with 2 characters after the initial one by executing `randstr('test1',2)`

Comment: Yeah, but you don't need `result = ""` as the next line overwrites `result` anyway